# Compiler error when instantiating std::mutex

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, std, deleted-functions

I have used std::mutex extensively in my codebase. However, one of the classes simply does not let me add a mutex to its instance variables list. I am instantiating the mutex quite simply using the following -

```
std::mutex myMutex;
```

I added the above statement to the private section of the class's members list.

I get the following error -

```
error C2280: 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\mutex(113) : see declaration of 'std::mutex::mutex'
```

The class I am trying to add the mutex gets copied.

As I said, I have used mutex all over my codebase, so it is very strange that I cannot instantiate the mutex in one place while I can instantiate in all other places. Can you please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Do you miss a `mutable`?

Comment: We need to see more code

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, do I need it? In any case, I tried making it mutable and the compiler still throws the same error.

Comment: @James, ok, let me see if I can add more.

Comment: We need to see more code. Somewhere, you are trying to copy a mutex. Post a self-contained, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You'll need it, when the mutex is used in `const` class member functions.

Comment: @user3670482 What are you expecting to happen to the mutex when you copy the class? Mutexes can't be copied.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I do copy the class.

Comment: @user3670482 Right, so that's the problem. You can't copy a mutex.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I wanted to add a vector<int> member to my class, and I was using the mutex to facilitate Getting and Setting the vector<int> member by using a mutex lock guard. Now that the mutex option is ruled out, how I do make operations on vector<int> threadSafe?

Comment: @user3670482 You can use a mutex. You just need to make class copy functions that don't try to copy the mutex.

Comment: @user3670482 Ask a new question

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, you were exactly right. I added a copy constructor and my code to add a member of std::vector<int> type with mutex protected getters and setters compiles successfully. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding a `std::mutex` to a class with a copy constructor. Most likely, your class has a default copy constructor that is being used. The default copy constructor calls the copy constructor on each member in the class. But `std::mutex`'s copy constructor is deleted, by spec – it's a non-copyable type.

Comment: Your comment put an end to my misery. Thank you very much